# Exact value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+k)(n+l)}$ for $k \in \Bbb{N}-\{0\}$ and $l \in \Bbb{N}-\{0,k\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The other day I was playing around with infinite sums and I found that for any fixed, positive integer $k$ the equality $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+k)} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n}$$ I got this result by using partial fraction decomposition and then cancelling out everything but a finite number of sums. This led me to seek a similar finite sum expression for $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+k)(n+l)}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nkl}-\frac{1}{k(n+k)(l-k)}+\frac{1}{l(n+l)(l-k)}$$ with fixed, positive integer $l \neq k$. Next I observed that the signs of some of the terms will change depending on whether $l>k$ or $k>l$, although I assume the final result has to be the same if a finite sum expression exists. At this point I decided to work on the case of $l>k$ and I broke apart the sum a bit with the hopes of canceling terms. I have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nkl}-\frac{1}{k(n+k)(l-k)}+\frac{1}{l(n+l)(l-k)} =\\ \frac{1}{kl}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{k(l-k)}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k}\right)+\frac{1}{l(l-k)}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+l}\right) \\ = \frac{1}{kl}\left(\sum_{n=1}^l \frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=l+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{k(l-k)}\left(\sum_{n=k+1}^l \frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=l+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{l(l-k)}\left(\sum_{n=l+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right)$$

**Edit:** This question was successfully answered, although now I cannot help but wonder about the next step. Given a finite collection of positive integers $\{k_i\}_{i=1}^m$ where $i \neq j \implies k_i \neq k_j$ for all $i,j \leq m$ then is there a closed form of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\prod_{i=1}^m(n+k_i)}$$ I won't be tackling this one, but if anyone on here feels up to it I would be very interested to see a result!

Comment: This looks as a very nice problem ! The only thing I can tell is that there is a closed form for the result. I shall follow your post. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici! So there is a closed form for the result? How do you know?

Comment: Using a CAS, I got it. But I am totally unable to prove anything. I was very interested by your post; this is why I looked at the solution.

Comment: Any chance you could post the closed form as an answer or in the comments? If I know what I'm working toward I might be able to get there :)

Comment: Here you get it; it is even simpler that "my" first result ! The CAS gave for the summation $$\frac{k H_l-l H_k}{k l (k-l)}$$ Good luck. By the way, I just saw Ron Gordon's answer; this is a good good track.

Comment: That is far more concise than I would've ever dreamed. And $H_l$ is the sum of the first $l$ harmonic numbers if I recall?

Comment: Note that the infinite sums cancel (the sum of the multipliers is zero), so that you need "only" evaluate the finite parts.

Comment: Yes, harmonic numbers. Short result, isn't it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to show that

$$\frac1{n (n+k) (n+\ell)} = \frac1{k \ell} \left ( \frac1{n}-\frac1{n+\ell} \right ) - \frac1{k (\ell-k)} \left ( \frac1{n+k}-\frac1{n+\ell}\right )$$

(I assumed that $\ell \gt k.$)

Thus,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n (n+k) (n+\ell)} = \frac1{k \ell} \sum_{n=1}^{\ell} \frac1{n} - \frac1{k (\ell-k)} \sum_{n=1}^{\ell-k} \frac1{k+n}$$

Comment: I am not seeing how to show that result above. In fact, for the case of $n=1=k, \space l=2$ I get $\frac{1}{6}$ on the LHS and $\frac{1}{2}$ on the RHS

Comment: Apologies...I made a sign error. Corrected.

Comment: No problem; this definitely seems to check out now. Have you noticed a change in the behavior of the series if $l<k$?

Comment: @graydad: there is symmetry in $k$ and $\ell$ so that their roles should simply be reversed.

Comment: That was my hunch; another user that answered this question mentioned a difference in behavior so I wanted to make sure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that reversing the roles of $k$ and $\ell$ does not change the formula. Both numerator and denominator have their signs reversed.

Answer (score 4):

Since 
$$\frac{1}{k\ell}-\frac{1}{k(\ell-k)} + \frac{1}{\ell(\ell-k)} = 0,$$
the infinite terms cancel, so we are left with
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{k\ell}\sum_{n=1}^\ell \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{k(\ell-k)}\sum_{n=k+1}^\ell \frac{1}{n}
   &= \frac{1}{k\ell}\sum_{n=1}^\ell \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{k(\ell-k)}\sum_{n=1}^\ell \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{k(\ell-k)}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n} \\
   &= -\frac{k}{k\ell(\ell-k)}H_\ell + \frac{1}{k(\ell-k)}H_k \\
   &= \frac{\ell H_k - k H_\ell}{k\ell(\ell-k)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: This seems promising. What does the phrase "the sum of the multipliers is zero" mean? I have not encountered that before

Comment: @graydad I clarified.